# Can not connect HM10 to Android device

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I am having problems connecting an Android device to my HM10 with an Arduino. I have managed to connect it with an iPhone, but the problem is when trying with Android. It gets to the function `public boolean connect(final String address)`, which is a function that is called when trying to connect to a device, but does not seem actually to connect to the device.

The code I used this project had been used earlier with a RedBearLabs BLE Shield and the code worked for that BLE device. Same thing for my Swift code for iPhone, but when changing to HM10 I only had to change the UUID and then everything was fine. This however does not seem to be the only change that I have to do for Android.

These are the UUID I use for Android:

```
public static String CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
public static String BLE_SHIELD_RX_TX = "0000FFF1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
public static String BLE_SHIELD_SERVICE = "0000FFF0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
```

The UUID for BLE_SHIELD_SERVICE and BLE_SHIELD_RX_TX I asked from the manufacturer (Feasycom).

These UUID is used for iPhone (should be the same?):

```
var characteristicUUID = CBUUID(string:"FFF1")
var serviceUUID = CBUUID(string:"FFF0")
```

Probably I forgot to mention something important, so please ask if there is anything that is unclear.